# If $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is a measure space, does all element of $\mathcal F$ are measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ a measure space.

**1)** Does all elements of $\mathcal F$ are measurable by definition ?

**2)** If $E\notin \mathcal F$, is it possible that $E$ is $\mu-$measurable ? Or $E$ is measurable $\iff$ $E\in\mathcal F$ ?

**3)** If there is $E\notin \mathcal F$ such that $E$ is $\mu-$measurable, does $E$ is of the form $E=F\cup Z$ where $Z$ is null (i.e. there is an $A\supset Z$ such that $\mu(A)=0$).

Let $(Y,\mathcal G,\nu)$ an other measurable space.

**4)** Let $A\times B$ a $\mu\times \nu-$ measurable. Does $(\mu\times \nu)(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ always ? (I mean, is it the definition of a product measure, or there is other product measure) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1,2,and 3 , the usual notation is that $\mu$ is a function with domain $dom  (\mu)=F$ and that "$E$ is $\mu-$ measurable" means $E\in F$. It may be possible to extend the domain of $\mu$ to a larger set, but the extended function should be given a different name..... For 4. for $A\in dom (\mu)$ and $B\in dom (\nu)$ the usual def'n is $(\mu \times \nu )(A\times B)=\mu (A)\nu (B)$ as you say. So $dom (\mu)\times dom (\nu)\subset dom (\mu \times \nu).$